# Error : Updating Calender from Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a script that can update the Google Calender from Google Spreadsheet.My Spreadsheet is like

> |A  | B | C | ------ |AS|AT|AU|

in my code

```
 function getRows(){
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var date = new Date(data[44][1]);
  var calId = "**************@group.calendar.google.com";
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  for (j=0,i=3;i<15;i++,j++) {

    var title=data[44][i];
    var tstart = new Date(data[9][i]);
    tstart.setDate(date.getDate());
    tstart.setMonth(date.getMonth());
    tstart.setYear(date.getYear());
    var tstop = new Date(data[9][i+1]);
    tstop.setDate(date.getDate());
    tstop.setMonth(date.getMonth());
    tstop.setYear(date.getYear());
    var desc="adkd";
    var loc="akskd";



    var id = data[44][26+j];  
    try {
      var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(id);
    }
    catch (e) {

    }
    if (!event) {

      var newEvent = cal.createEvent(title, tstart, tstop, {description:desc,location:loc}).getId();

      data[44][26+j] = newEvent;  
    }
    else {
      event.setTitle(title);
      event.setDescription(desc);
      event.setLocation(loc);

      var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addDailyRule().times(1);
      event.setRecurrence(recurrence, tstart, tstop);
    }
    debugger;
    range.setValues(data);
  }

  }
```

In this i am getting an error as

> Incorrect range width was 27 but should be 24

i increased the column numbers.But still i am getting this error.

Comment: What is the limit for j in your for loop?

Comment: It is same as i, instead of using (i-3) me used  assigned j

Answer (score 0):

instead of `range.setValues(data);` you should try

```
sheet.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

so you'll be sure that the `range` has the right size (at least if `data` is homogeneous (same number of columns in each row)

---

### EDIT

Here is a script to "normalize your output array so that it can be used as value in `setValues()`.

In this example I push values `'Z'` to see it more easily in the logger (for demo) but of course you should replace the `'Z'` with `''` so that it only adds empty cells.

I join a test function and the Logger result below.

```
function test(){
  var array = [['xx','xx'],['xx','xx','xx'],['xx','xx','xx','xx','xx'],['xx','xx','xx','xx','xx','xx','xx']];
Logger.log('array '+JSON.stringify(array)+'\n becomes '+JSON.stringify(arrayNormalize(array)));
}

function arrayNormalize(array) {
  var lenMax = 0;
  for(var n in array){
    if(array[n].length>lenMax){lenMax = array[n].length };
  }
  Logger.log('max array width = '+lenMax);
  for(var n in array){
    while(array[n].length<lenMax){
      array[n].push('Z');
    };
  }
  return array;
}
```

[image]

use this function as follows in your code :

```
var newData = arrayNormalize(data);
sheet.getRange(1,1,newData.length,newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
```

Comment: It means that your array does not have the same length in every row...as I said above, this is a mandatory condition.

Comment: Can you help in reading and writing from a spreadsheet having rows with variable length ?

Comment: sorry, was on holiday for a couple of days with just my cellphone and no computer... so I'm a bit late but see edit with a new code to solve your issue.